# Jenkins declarative pipeline - success state of skiped conditional stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In a Jenkins declarative pipeline, I have a conditional stage. For example :

```
stage('Sonar Scan') {
    when {
        expression { config.skipSonar == false }
    }
    steps {
        // ...
    }
}
```

During a build, if `skipSonar` is `true`, Jenkins "Stage view" still display a success state (green table cell, with a execution time). Even if the stage has been skiped because the `when` expression returned false.

[image]

And if I click on the "Logs" button, on the cell, the pop-up display nothing (which is logical : the stage has been skiped).

[image]

Is there a way to avoid the "Success" state when a conditional stage is skiped ? For example, display a grey cell, like when a stage was not present in the Jenkinsfile of previous builds.

**Edit:**

I just found this JIRA issue : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-47286.

So I guess I have my answer : no, there is no way...

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy in scripted pipeline but I think it is an open issue in declarative pipeline : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41012